# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Arts & Crafts's [first moderator election](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Lyssagal] [image: Joachim]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6182767776759808/0).

Comment: All the best to both of you! You are a fine choice.

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations and welcome on board :)